# Sci-fi movie. Boy receives gift of space helmet from older relative. Alien apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to locate the name of a movie where an older male relative (father?  grandfather?) gifts his son/grandson a NASA helmet. He wears it and falls asleep. When he wakes up, everyone is dead. It ends up being because of aliens.

My dad saw it as a child, probably around the 70s/80s/90s

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) Where was he? US, Europe, somewhere else? I'm assuming this was an American movie because of NASA, but NASA's pretty well known and not everyone has a space agency, so it'd be handy if you could clarify where this film was likely made and released?